# parametric equation of a intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have this two equations:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$
$$x+y+z=0$$

And I have to do the intersection and get the parametric equations for $x,y,z$. So I did a first step $$z=-x-y$$ and I put it in my first equation. Then my final equation was $$ x^2+xy+y^2=1/2$$ but I don't know how I should proceed know. I saw in wolfram alpha that it is a ellipse with a rotation but I don't know how I should work with $xy$.

Thanks in advance for the help,I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In polar coordinates,

$$\rho^2+\rho^2\cos\theta\sin\theta=\frac12$$ or

$$\rho=\frac1{\sqrt{2(1+\cos\theta\sin\theta)}}.$$

Then

$$\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{2(1+\cos\theta\sin\theta)}},
\\y=\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{2(1+\cos\theta\sin\theta)}},
\\z=-\dfrac{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}{\sqrt{2(1+\cos\theta\sin\theta)}}.\end{cases}$$

---

The solution is more elegant in spherical coordinates: $\rho=1$, and

$$(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)\sin\phi+\cos\phi=0.$$

$$\begin{cases}x=-\cos\theta\sin(\text{arccot}(\cos\theta+\sin\theta))
\\y=-\sin\theta\sin(\text{arccot}(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)),
\\z=\cos(\text{arccot}(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)).\end{cases}$$

---

But a yet more elegant solution is obtained by means of a 3D rotation that brings the normal to the plane in the vertical direction. The change of variable reads

$$\begin{cases}w=\dfrac{x+y+z}{\sqrt3},\\
v=\dfrac{x-y}{\sqrt2},\\
u=\dfrac{x-2y+z}{\sqrt6}.\end{cases}$$

The sphere has the equation

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=u^2+v^2+w^2=1$$ and the plane $$w=0.$$

Then

$$u^2+v^2=1$$ is a circle, which can be generated by
$$\begin{cases}u=\cos\theta,\\v=\sin\theta,\\
w=0.\end{cases}$$

The final equations are obtained by multiplying by the inverse rotation matrix, which is also the transpose.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

A rotated ellipse, centered at the origin, is always given by an equation of the form :
$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 = 1$$
where $A,C>0$ and $B^2 - 4AC < 0$.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know it!